# Reformat 64gb/128gb SD Card to FAT32

Tags: sd-card, raspberry-pi-os, exfat

From what I've read the raspberry OS bootloader only supports FAT32 partitions, which aren't default on 32gb+ sd cards. (even thhough most stuff I read seems to conflict with the documentation; https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#sd-cards)

I saw this post previously: [Why does my 128GB sd card work?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/130377/why-does-my-128gb-sd-card-work), but I do not understand where to choose to reformat the sd card (I formatted it in SD Card Formatter, with the Overwrite format option) and am going to use the standard Imager software... Currently the file system is exFAT:
[image]

Further, does changing the format from exFAT somehow make the sd card less efficient, why don't we format all of them, no matter the size, to FAT32?

Comment: As joan points out, there is no purpose in pre-formatting the card before you write an image to it.    There could be absolutely anything on the card, it does not matter -- it all gets overwritten, including any formatting meta data etc.

Answer (score 1):

The boot partition needed on the SD card is tiny.  Perhaps a 100 megabytes or so.  It needs to be in FAT format to be universally recognised.

The rest of the SD card will be formatted in a Linux format (EXT4 currently).

The imaging process will overwrite any formatting you have done on the SD card.